# S Planner (Mini) widget in Galaxy Note 2 (running on 4.1.2 JB) doesn't update

Tags: app-widgets, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Recently added the S Planner (Mini) widget to the home screen to have a quick glance of my calendar for the current day. But the widget is not updating by itself. When I tap on 'Today' then the date and the events are updated. Am I missing any setting for the automatic update for the widget?